# Handling signal in libcurl C++

Tags: c++, libcurl, sigint

I am exploring libcurl library in C++. 
Want to try out a simple use case: 
**"While download is running, I want my program to terminate, if SIGINT is received."** 
I tried to search curl_easy_setopt options, but I didn't find such any. I think CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL will not help me to handle SIGINT.

Any suggestions?

My test code:

```
CURL *curlhandle = NULL;

curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_SSL);

curlhandle = curl_easy_init();

if ( curlhandle ) {

curl_easy_setopt(curlhandle, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 0L);

curl_easy_setopt(curlhandle, CURLOPT_URL, "myURL/samplefile");

curl_easy_setopt(curlhandle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);

FILE *file = fopen("filepath", "wb");

if(file) {

    curl_easy_setopt(curlhandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void*)file);

    /* get it! */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curlhandle);

    /* close the file */
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: Install a signal handler for `SIGINT` at the beginning of your program or just leave it at default (terminate). I don't see what `curl` has to do with anything.

Comment: Libcurl doesn't install SIGINT handler anyway. So you don't need to do anything as the default action for SIGINT is to terminate (which is what you said you want to do on SIGINT).

Comment: I think I got confused between the blocking behaviour of curl_easy_perform and SIGINT handling.